# How to install django-utils?

Tags: python, django, installation, virtualenv, django-extensions

I tried installing django-utils from source code from github and using pip. The installation goes fine however the `queue_command` does not work within my django app.

So as suggested in the [docs](http://charlesleifer.com/docs/djutils/django-utils/getting_started.html#installation), I tried running `python setup.py test' and I get the following error. I have not idea how to fix this. I am running from within virtualenv on mac snow leopard.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

```
running test
running egg_info
writing djutils.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to djutils.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to djutils.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'djutils.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'LICENSE.txt'
writing manifest file 'djutils.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 33, in <module>
    tests_require=['pygments', 'PIL>=0.1.5', 'httplib2'],
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/test.py", line 121, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/test.py", line 101, in with_project_on_sys_path
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/test.py", line 130, in run_tests
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 128, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 91, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "/Users/miki725/Development/libs/django-utils/runtests.py", line 43, in <module>
    from django.test.simple import run_tests
  File "/Users/miki725/Development/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.test.client import Client, RequestFactory
  File "/Users/miki725/Development/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 27, in <module>
    from django.db import close_connection
  File "/Users/miki725/Development/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/miki725/Development/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/miki725/Development/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/miki725/Development/Django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 51, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sqlite3' isn't an available database backend.
Try using django.db.backends.sqlite3 instead.
Error was: No module named base
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Django are you running? 1.3 deprecated the old-style way of specifying databases, for example, using just 'sqlite3'. You now must specify the entire import path, i.e. `django.db.backends.sqlite3`.

However, I was pretty sure that 1.3 still let you use the old-style way and simply fussed at you, warning that it's deprecated. Perhaps I was wrong though. If you're running off trunk, then, it's almost certainly fully deprecated, which makes that error a little more understandable.

The long and short is that since the last update of django-utils was back in 2009, it's effectively dead, and Django has moved on.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your `settings.py`
2. Replace `'ENGINE': 'sqlite3',` with `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',`
3. Save

Try again.

Comment: which setting.py. I am installing a python lib. I am not operating on any django project at that point.